# How do I attach jQuery .live() to this snippet of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin called cloud zoom. the problem is, it attaches itself to anything with `class="cloud-zoom"` when the DOM is ready. My problem is I don't attach that class to DOM elements at render time. It is appended dynamically. So I need somehow to mix .live() with it to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
});
```

.live() expects an event. I'm not sure how to specify an event called invoke CloudZoom() on any element that gets injected into the DOM with the class cloud-zoom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here, it works in a very different event-driven specific way.  For plugins on dynamic elements there are 2 options, either re-run this code when new elements come in, for example in your ajax `success` handler, or using [the `.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').livequery(function() {
      $(this).CloudZoom();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll try this and post back. I'm not using XHR here. My images are available after the DOM is loaded. The problem is only one at a time is available in the div where the class cloud-zoom is. When I hover over a mini image, it comes into the main-image tab and I need to apply this.

Comment: BTW, I'm getting a lot of this in the console when trying this: Expected identifier for class selector but found 'parent'.

Comment: @randombits - from the plugin?

Comment: Actually I figured it out and livequery did the trick. Awesome plugin, thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be something like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').live(function(){
        $(this).CloudZoom();
    });    
});
```

Ok, nevermind, it expects an event. I was thinking about jQuery Livequery plugin, which accepts anonymous function without event

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about livequery, as stated in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the above doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').live(function(){
    $(this).CloudZoom();
}).trigger('click');
```

});

Just add the trigger click at the end, works for me.